# Deploy production Laravel app Capistrano environment symlinks

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, rubygems, capistrano

I have deployed a Rails app with Capistrano where I  learned a lot about the process of Capistrano. Using Capistrano to deploy Laravel is a little bit more difficult with setting up symlinks for the .env file.

The deploy is completing on Centos 8, but I am not able to setup the final .env file correctly. I am a little new to Laravel so a bit unsure about production setup.

Do I need to setup a symlink or just have a .env.php file in git? I would prefer to keep a file in the server rather than keeping these details in git.

I have tried to create the symlinks

```
set :linked_files, "shared/config/.env"
```

and manual link creation to the

```
after :updated, :build do
  #execute :ln, "-sf #{shared_path}/config/.env #{deploy_to}/current/.env"
```

but I feel like I am going in the wrong direction here.

I think the intention is to keep config files in app/shared/config/.env  or .env.php

But setting up a symlink in the app/current/.env directory to the shared/config/.env is causing me a headache. what is the best way to present the env file to Laravel?

Thanks

Comment: why not use [deployer](https://deployer.org/) its a pure php code and there is already a [recipe](https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/master/recipe/laravel.php) available for laravel

Comment: This is a good option I am trying out. Thank you. Perhaps this would be a good answer to give rather than a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i deploy using [deployer](https://deployer.org/) all you have to do is configure ssh and add ssh key to your server to authenticate automatically. Then change the repository url and hostname

laravel Recipe:
https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/master/recipe/laravel.php

Repo url:

```
set('repository', 'git@github.com:user/myproject.git');
```

HostName:

```
host('mydomain.com')->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/html');
```

Finally deploy:

```
dep deploy
```

and you could define custom tasks such as `gulp` or `webpack`

```
 task('build:gulp', function () {
 }
```

Read the documentation [here](https://deployer.org/docs/getting-started.html)

P.S. make sure the server has access to repository :)

Comment: Tthis was nice and easy to setup once I got used to slightly different config from Capistrano. Actually is clean and well thought out.